# browserify an angular app into one js bundle is good practice?

Tags: angularjs, browserify

I'm currently building an angular app with browserify ends up everything is in a bundle js file including angular.js itself and other vendor libs. I am wondering is it a common practice for using browserify or I'm doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't say you're doing anything *wrong*; its a matter of preference.

I would personally create 2 separate bundles, application and libs, just because I prefer to have that separation in my build.

With separation, upgrading/swapping libs won't require a re-bundle of application logic, and updates to the app won't require a re-bundle of libs. Based on how your build is structured this could increase speed & efficiency, especially if you have watches in place.

Comment: so how to require among bundles - vendors / app?

Comment: This post may help you in configuring things correctly for your build process https://lincolnloop.com/blog/speedy-browserifying-multiple-bundles/